# Cyclic projective $R$-module result

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I am wondering if the following statement is true.

*Let $R$ be a ring with unity, and $P := R\{v\}$ a cyclically generated projective $R$-module. Then the submodule $Q:= R\{u\}$ of $P$, where $u = rv$ for some $r \in R$, is projective.*  Note that $R\{v\}$ denotes the $R$-span of the single element $v$.

I've tried proving this by showing any epimorphism $f : X \to Q$ (on an arbitrary $R$-module $X$) has a section map $f' : Q \to X$, satisfying $ff' = 1_Q$. However, my proof hinged on assuming that any epimorphism $f : X \to Q$ can be extended to an epimorphism $\hat{f} : Y \to P$, where $X \subseteq Y$, and $f = \hat{f}$ on $X$. Although I am doubtful of this approach.

Any help would be apprectaited! Thanks in advance.

Comment: With $v=1$, this would imply $R$ is [Rickart](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/72/), and not all rings are Rickart.  (The solution by azif00 provides an example of a non-Rickart ring.) So your problem statement is incorrect. At this point, if you discover you've omitted something, you'll have to post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False. If $R$ is the ring $\newcommand{\Z}{\Bbb Z} \Z/4\Z = \{\bar0, \bar1, \bar2, \bar3\}$, then $P := R\{\bar 1\} = R$ is projective, but $Q := R\{\bar2\} = 2\Z/4\Z \cong \Z/2\Z$ is not.